# Is this conversion correct?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I've tried converting this ASP code to PHP, and would like to know if it is correct:

ASP:

```
Set emp = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

EM_GENERAL=0
EM_AUDIO=1
EM_VIDEO=2 

emp.Add EM_GENERAL, "General"
emp.Add EM_AUDIO, "Audio"
emp.Add EM_VIDEO, "Video"

For each em in Emp
Response.Write "<option value=" + CStr(em)
If em = CInt(IT_FIELD) Then
    Response.Write " selected"
End If
Response.Write ">"
Response.Write Emp.Item(em)
Next
```

PHP:

```
$EM_GENERAL=0;
$EM_AUDIO=1;
$EM_VIDEO=2;

$emp = array();
$emp[$EM_GENERAL] = "General";
$emp[$EM_AUDIO] = "Audio";
$emp[$EM_VIDEO] = "Video";

foreach ($emp as $em) {
  echo "<option value=" + ($em);
  if ($em == intval($IT_FIELD)) {
    echo " selected";
  }
  echo ">";
  echo $em;
}
```

Comment: Your check is as simple as: Do they produce the same output? If so, it's correct. You're also outputting (in both cases) terribly formed HTML. You're going to wind up with things like `<option value=General selected>General`. No closing tag, no quotes around attribute values...

Comment: For code reviews there's http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB, the `For Each` loop iterates over the Dictionary keys, not the values, so in your ASP code, em is the numeric key of your emp entries. In PHP, `foreach` iterates over the values, so `$em` is the value, not the key. Your `if ($em == intval($IT_FIELD))` check will not work as expected. Fortunately the php foreach loop also supports the syntax `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`, where `$value` would be equivalent to `Dictionary.Item(key)`.

Try this instead:

```
foreach ($emp as $em => $value) {
  echo "<option value=" + ($em);
  if ($em == intval($IT_FIELD)) {
    echo " selected";
  }
  echo ">";
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, though you could change it to this with the same effect (PHP creates indexes starting from 0 if you don't specify them): $emp = array(); $emp[] = "General"; $emp[] = "Audio"; $emp[] = "Video";